# Psoc 4 ADC and PSoC Creator 4.2

Tags: adc, psoc

I have been trying to read in values from the ADC of the Psoc 4700s, but I have not been successful with producing results. I am using the 10 bit ADC described in this  [datasheet](https://www.cypress.com/file/442036/download), but I still can't find any tutorials using this ADC. 
In my code I start the ADC, Start Conversion, and read, but I am still not getting any values. Here is some code that I am using:

```
 ADC_Start();
 ADC_StartConvert(0u);
 uint16 val = ADC_ReadResult_mVolts(0u);
```

However in the debug mode I am receiving ***optimized_out*** for the value of val, but other variables have values so I know that the debugger is working.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I looked up the problem for receiving *optimized_out* for values and it was because the compiler was optimized and seemed to change something with the variables when debugging. I turned off the compiler optimization and the ADC works now also I took out the second line of code above since it is called in the third line. I do plan on turning on the compiler optimization back on when I am done debugging though.